# не могу найти ошибку в коде на питоне

Tags: python

я решала следующую задачу на питоне:

> Найти минимальное и максимальное из чётных положительных чисел,
> записанных в файле input.txt . Количество чисел неизвестно.  Если в
> файле нет чётных положительных чисел, нужно вывести число 0.
> Результат записать в файл output.txt .

Причем в задаче ввод вывод должны быть выполнены в двух файлах. У меня получился код:

```
with open ("input.txt") as file:
    counter=0 
    mi=100001 
    ma=0
    for line in file:
        num=int(line)
        if num%2==0 and num>=0:
            if num<mi:
                mi=num 
                counter+=1
            if num>ma:
                ma=num 
                counter+=1
            else:
                counter+=1
    if counter==0:
        print(0, file=open("output.txt", "w"))
    else:
         print(mi, ma, file=open("output.txt", "w"))
```

Моя проблема в том, что после отправки кода в проверяющую систему (информатикс) оказалось, что на 7 тестов программа выдает неверный ответ (к сожалению, эти тесты неизвестны). Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Откуда вы знаете, что минимум меньше `100001`? Используйте `None` в качестве индикатора отсутствия значения:

```py
mi = None
...
            if mi is None or num < mi:
                mi = num
```

2. Файл для вывода нужно открывать так же через `with`, как и для ввода. Иначе нет гарантии, что содержимое буфера будет уже записано в файл в момент проверки.
3. Положительное число - это число строго больше нуля, так что не `num >= 0`, а `num > 0` проверка должна быть.
4. Ну и тут не сказано, какой должен быть формат вывода в файл, если минимум и максимум найдены. Может там они на отдельных строках должны быть, например?

Comment: отправила доработанную версию, но проблемы остались(((

Comment: @Настя Попробуйте строгую проверку `num > 0`

Comment: спасибо!!! это все исправило!!!